# Get date function not working

Tags: php, functions, date-time, date

I have a function to get the date. I have input fields and want the date in this fields. But my code is set a wrong date. I set the date in Wordpress settings and on my server. But it is not working. This is my script:

```
function get_agenda_item_day() {
    global $post; 

        $cp_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_date_end', true); 
        $cp_date_arr = explode("-",$cp_date);
        $day = $cp_date_arr[2];

    return $day;
}
```

And i use this in my select tag:

```
<?php $day = get_the_time('j'); ?> 
<select name="ad" id="ad" onChange="getNDay()" class="select select-n">
                    <option <?php if($day == 1) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="1">1</option>
                    <option <?php if($day == 2) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="2">2</option>
                    <option <?php if($day == 3) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="3">3</option>
                    <option <?php if($day == 4) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="4">4</option>
etc etc etc
</select>
```

But, what do i wrong. Always the date is 17 juni in the select box. Because today the date is 5 Juli.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the second parameter `$post` to `get_the_time('j')`:

```
get_the_time( 'j', $post );
```

If you don’t WordPress will just use whatever the current global post object is.

Comment: This is not working. It results in 17 juni. Because it is not 17 juni

Comment: Did you actually try what toscho suggested?

Please be aware that get_the_time() returns the time a certain post **was posted**. If you don't specify a post it will return the post time for the current post out of the main loop (global $post). If it returns "17. june" it means that the current post was posted at that time!

Comment: I interpret your question as you wanting to extract a date from post meta. If this is the case, then you need to store it in post meta first.

The best would be to update your description with more details and some more code.